# How to traceback a warning to get the line number where it occurred?

Tags: python, pandas, logging, warnings, traceback

I have some codes written in Python and used pandas to make and manipulate some DataFrames. In a few of them, I get some warnings. for example settingwithcopywarning or performancewarning. I want to catch the ***line number*** that warning has occured and for that, I wrote the following code. I catch everything but the **line number**.

```
scripts = ['myfile.py', 'myotherfile.py']
with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
    # Cause all warnings to always be triggered.
    warnings.simplefilter("default")
    for s in scripts:
        with open(s) as f:
            try:
                exec(f.read())
            except Exception as e:
                print('An Error happend during the execution', e)
            finally:    
                f.close()    

    print(color.orange('There are {} error/s happend in {}.'.format(len(w), s)))
    for i in range(0, len(w)):
        print(color.green('LineNo: '), w[i].lineno)
        print(color.green('Line: '), w[i].line)
        print(color.green('warning category: '), w[i].category.__name__)
        print(color.green('Warning: '), w[i].message) 
        print(color.green('filename: '), w[i].file) 
        print(color.cyan('-' * 40))
```

also I changed the `warnings.simplefilter("default")` to `warnings.simplefilter("error")` to trace them back however, it works just when the first exception happens.which is logical but I want to get the whole traceback for all warnings. by the way, that does not work when the warning time is `PerformnceWarning`

```
try:
    exec(f.read())     
except Exception:
    lg.getLogger("error_logger").error(traceback.format_exc())
```

I expect to get the line number for the original file not the python core modules that the warnings logged

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I figure out and access pandas warning subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999877/how-can-i-figure-out-and-access-pandas-warning-subclasses) [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392099/how-to-find-the-line-that-is-generating-a-pandas-settingwithcopywarning).