# Is there a way to see which line of code produces warning message in python?

Tags: python, warnings

Python often throws warning messages, especially when working with pandas. But no line reference is shown. Why is that and is there a way to get that info?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the line that is generating a Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392099/how-to-find-the-line-that-is-generating-a-pandas-settingwithcopywarning)

Answer (score 1):

For a more general solution that is not pandas specific you can override the [formatwarning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.formatwarning) method:

> The printing of warning messages is done by calling showwarning(),
> which may be overridden; the default implementation of this function
> formats the message by calling formatwarning(), which is also
> available for use by custom implementations.

So it can look something like the following:

```
import warnings

def my_formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line=None):
  print(message, category)
  # lineno is the line number you are looking for
  print('file:', filename, 'line number:', lineno) 
  ...

warnings.formatwarning = my_formatwarning
```

For the why part of the question I am not really sure what the answer is, I suppose so that the log is kept cleaner?